# Split a string into array of characters BUT group nearby vowels together

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've been looking for the solution to this, but couldn't find it. I want to take a string like "great" and turn it into the following array: `(g,r,ea,t)`.
Basically, I want all the vowels `(a,e,i,o,u,y)` to be combined IF they are together. If not, like in the case of "fate", then I should just get `(f,a,t,e)`. I can easily get this last array, but I don't know how to get the first one.

I've been thinking about doing a foreach loop and using a counter to detect any grouped vowels, but that seems unnecessarily complicated, yet I can't figure out a faster way.. Any suggestions?

Comment: what you have tried???

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I was hoping there was a built in function to take care of this, maybe a variation of str_split() or something..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using [preg_split](http://php.net/preg_split)

```
$word = 'great';
var_dump(preg_split('/([^aeiouy])/i', $word, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
//                   ^ split string by none vowels
//                                              ^ but catch none vowels as delimiter
```